# Properties instead of values in J2EE 7 Rest client

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I'm trying to consume a webservice with a response like the following

```
<oxip version="7.1" created="2014-11-18 14:25:20" lastMsgId="" requestTime="0.0174">
  <response request="getPoolResults" code="001" message="success" debug="" provider="GENERIC">
    <disclaimer></disclaimer>
    <pool id="979" name="Auto Pool-2014-11-11 09:00:00" poolType="MLJT" closesAt="2014-11-17 20:00:00" displayOrder="" resulted="N" lastUpdateDate="2014-11-18" lastUpdateTime="14:24:57">
      <poolPrizes>
        <prize numCorrect="3" winners="0" guarantee="0" value="18.00" size="18.0"/>
      </poolPrizes>
      <event id="15854" name="Barnet v Cameroun" scoreHome="" scoreAway="" outcomeId="" poolResultStatus="" lastUpdateDate="2014-11-14" lastUpdateTime="13:43:51"/>
      <event id="15855" name="Celtic v Clydebank" scoreHome="" scoreAway="" outcomeId="" poolResultStatus="" lastUpdateDate="2014-11-14" lastUpdateTime="13:43:51"/>
      <event id="15856" name="Barcelona v Arbroath" scoreHome="" scoreAway="" outcomeId="" poolResultStatus="" lastUpdateDate="2014-11-14" lastUpdateTime="13:43:51"/>
    </pool>
  </response>
</oxip>
```

So only properties - no values. I'm consuming it like

```
WebTarget oxipTarget = ClientBuilder.newClient().target(<URL>);
oxip = oxipTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(Oxip.class);
```

And `Oxip` is the base root of the hiearchy

But only the instances are created I get no values in my instances. How can I get the properties as values inside my instances ?

From my log I can sew the following (log from each constructor)

```
creating Oxip 
creating Response 
creating Disclaimer 
creating Pool 
creating Prize
creating Event 
creating Event 
creating Event
```

(I'll properly have an issue with 3 events not in a events list - I'm trying to get the producer to change this)

kind regards
 Torben

Comment: So NONE of the values are getting populated? Or Just the Events no being populated?

Comment: I'm almost sure Java EE isn't called J2EE anymore since Java EE 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object will be created (hence the constructor call), but if the field/properties of the class are not annotated correctly, the values will not be populated if matches can't be found (i.e. null values). Element attributes, should be annotated with `@XmlAttribute`. If you leave this annotation out, the properties will be default to `@XmlElement`. And if an element by that name can't be found, nothing will get populated.

Collections are little bit more tricky. For example for `<poolPrizes>`, since you don't have a `PoolPrizes` class, you need to annotate `List<Prize>` with `@XmlElementWrapper(name = "poolPrizes")`. And the `List<Event>`, if the field/property name does not match the xml element name, then it should be annotated with `@XmlElement(name = "event")` (the last part really applies to all properties though)

I decided to play around with your XML, and here's a solution that will work (tested)

`Oxip`

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Oxip {
    @XmlElement
    protected Response response;
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String id;
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String created;
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String lastMsgId;
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String requestTime;
    // GETTER and SETTERS
}
```

`Respoonse`

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Response {
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String request;
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String code;
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String message;
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String debug;
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String provider;
    @XmlElement
    protected Disclaimer disclaimer;
    @XmlElement
    protected Pool pool;
    // GETTERS and SETTERS
}
```

`Disclaimer`

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Disclaimer {  
}
```

`Pool`

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Pool {
    @XmlElement(name = "prize")
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "poolPrizes")
    protected List<Prize> poolPrizes;
    @XmlElement(name = "event")
    private List<Event> events;  
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String id;
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String name;
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String poolType;
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String closesAt;
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String displayOrder;
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String resulted;
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String lastUpdateDate;
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String lastUpdateTime;
    // GETTER and SETTERS
}
```

`Prize`

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Prize {      
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String numCorrect;
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String winners;
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String guarantee;
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String value;
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String size;
    // GETTERS and SETTERS
}
```

`Event`

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Event {
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String id;
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String name;
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String scoreHome;
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String scoreAway;
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String outcomeId; 
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String poolResultStatus; 
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String lastUpdateDate; 
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String lastUpdateTime;
    // GETTERS and SETTERS
}
```

---

- Have a look at the [JAXB Tutorial](https://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_1_1-Introduction.html#Introduction) to learn more about these annotations.